# Can UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication be nil?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Recently after a new app update, we start getting crash in line

```
let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String
```

in the following code. I am just wondering why it can be nil or is it crashing because of as! to string?

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    CoreAnalytics.shared.record("AppDelegate", action: "Open URL")
    Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url)
    let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String
    let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]

    CleverTap.sharedInstance()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)

    return
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) ||
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was happening while opening the app from the Apple wallet pass.